# Flexbox, min-height, margin auto and Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I use to play with both `display: flex` and `margin: auto` to have this kind of layouts:
[image]

This works well on every browser supporting Flexbox, even IE.
However, it would have been too easy if there hadn't had a little exception: `min-height`.

You can find a simple working example here. When using `min-height` on my wrapper, the last element **is not** pushed to the bottom of this wrapper (IE only).

I can't get this to works, do you girls/guys have any idea? Thanks.

*Testing on IE11*

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 300px;
  
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px;
}
.element {
  height: 35px;
  
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 5px;
}
.element:last-child {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ``position: absolute`` can be a workaround here. IE11, flexbox and ``height`` & ``min-height`` and heights overall are very bad friends. I had tons of issues with IE11 layout in flexbox

Comment: here's KIND OF a workaround http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGVaZX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This is a bug in IE's `flexbox` implementation:**

> In all other browsers that support flexbox, a `flex-direction:column` based flex container will honor the containers `min-height` to calculate `flex-grow` lengths. In IE10 & 11-preview it only seems to work with an explicit `height` value.

*Bug report* - (https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/802625/min-height-and-flexbox-flex-direction-column-dont-work-together-in-ie-10-11-preview#tabs)

It appears that this is on Microsoft's radar and will be fixed some point in the future:

> Unfortunately, we are not able to address this feedback in our upcoming release. We will consider your feedback for a future release. We will keep this connect feedback bug active to track this request.

*Reply from Microsoft* - (https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/802625/min-height-and-flexbox-flex-direction-column-dont-work-together-in-ie-10-11-preview#tabs)

**For now the simple solution is to use height:**

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.element {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.element:last-child {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

But this has the limitation that the box wont grow if more `.element`s are added so probably isn't what you are after.

**There does appear to be a somewhat hacky way of achieving this although it does require an extra containing element:**

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  min-height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.element {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.element:last-child {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This adds a container (`.container`), sets it to `display: table;` and gives it `max-height: 300px;`. `height: 100%;` is then added to `.wrapper` to get it to fit the full height of `.container` (effectively `300px`) thus making IE behave the same as other browsers.

Compliant browsers ignore this and will continue to follow the `min-height: 300px;` rule set on `.wrapper`.

Comment: I came to the same solution: the extra container. *sigh*

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution:

Adding an additional container with 2 elements:

- an element with an height of "300px"
- your ".wrapper"

```css
.container {
  display: flex;    
}
.min-height-fix {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 300px; /* the "min-height" */
  width: 1px; /* DEBUG */
  background: red; /* DEBUG */
}
.wrapper {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*min-height: 300px;*/
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.element {
  height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 5px;
}
.element:last-child {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="min-height-fix">
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```